# How would I size each transaction executed in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql

I would like to get the size of a stored procedure but as a sum of every size of each transaction executed.

Comment: What is the *size* of a stored procedure? And what is the *size* of a transaction?

Comment: The size of a transaction would be the physical space they occupy and the size of a SP would be the sum of the size of every transaction contained in the sp .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**`sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-procedure-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Returns aggregate performance statistics for cached stored procedures.
>   The view returns one row for each cached stored procedure plan, and
>   the lifetime of the row is as long as the stored procedure remains
>   cached. When a stored procedure is removed from the cache, the
>   corresponding row is eliminated from this view. At that time, a
>   Performance Statistics SQL trace event is raised similar to
>   sys.dm_exec_query_stats.

**Example:**

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.object_id, d.database_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'proc name',   
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,  
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],  
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count  
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d  
ORDER BY [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

Comment: what about the size of the transaction ? is there a way to get it as a sum of every transaction size contained in the sp ?

Comment: @Drey `total_worker_time` - The total amount of CPU time, in microseconds, that was consumed by executions of this stored procedure since it was compiled.

Comment: How do you know that this question relates to SQLServer? While this might answer the question, you probably should explicitly state the RDBMS it relates to.